# Refresh renditions using Javascript SDK in Content Hub

Tags: content-hub, content-hub-scripting

Is there any way we can refresh renditions using `Javascript SDK`?

I know we can do this with triggers and `action scripts` or using `Web client SDK` but I need to do this with `Javascript SDK`.

Comment: We achieved this previously with action script and web client SDK as well, is there any reason you want to achieve this with Javascript SDK?

Comment: I am creating one react based external component which will be placed on asset detail page, it will have one simple button and clicking on this button will refresh all the renditions, as of now you can't do this on asset detail page you have to do this from asset listing page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Below is the code snippet for refreshing the renditions through Javascript SDK.

```
// Create the JavaScript SDK client
    const client = new ContentHubClient(endpoint, oauth);
    var isAuthenticate = await client.internalClient.authenticateAsync();
    console.log(isAuthenticate);
    var jobEntity = null;
    jobEntity = await client.entityFactory.createAsync("M.Job");
    jobEntity.setPropertyValue("Job.Type", "MassEdit");
    jobEntity.setPropertyValue("Job.State", "Created");
    jobEntity.setPropertyValue("Job.Condition", "Pending");
    jobEntity.setPropertyValue("Job.TargetCount", 0);
    jobEntity.setPropertyValue("Job.TargetsCompleted", 0);
    var jobId = await client.entities.saveAsync(jobEntity);

    var descriptionEntity = await client.entityFactory.createAsync(
      "M.JobDescription"
    );
    var jobConfiguration = {
      $type:
        "Stylelabs.M.Base.MassEdit.MassEditJobDescription, Stylelabs.M.Base",
      Operations: [
        {
          $type:
            "Stylelabs.M.Base.MassEdit.RefreshRenditionsOperation, Stylelabs.M.Base",
          Renditions: [],
          FailedOnly: true,
          RefreshHistory: false,
          RefreshSubfiles: false,
        },
      ],
      FinalizeOperations: [],
      Targets: [assetId],
    };

    console.log(jobConfiguration);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jobConfiguration));
    descriptionEntity.setPropertyValue("Job.Configuration", jobConfiguration);

    var jobRel = descriptionEntity.getRelation(
      "JobToJobDescription",
      RelationRole.Child
    );
    if (jobRel != null) {
      jobRel.setIds([jobId]);
      var descriptionId = await client.entities.saveAsync(descriptionEntity);
      console.log(descriptionId);

      var loadConfig = new EntityLoadConfiguration();

      loadConfig.propertyLoadOption = new PropertyLoadOption([
        "Job.State",
        "Job.TargetCount",
      ]);
      loadConfig.relationLoadOption = RelationLoadOption.None;
      loadConfig.cultureLoadOption = CultureLoadOption.Default;

      jobEntity = await client.entities.getAsync(jobId, loadConfig);

      if (jobEntity != null) {
        console.log(jobEntity);
        jobEntity.setPropertyValue("Job.State", "Pending");
        jobEntity.setPropertyValue("Job.TargetCount", 1);
        await client.entities.saveAsync(jobEntity);
      }
    }
```